# (Bayesian) Quadrature when the density can be factorised with respect to a directed graph

Tags: bayesian, gaussian-process, numerical-integration

I am very new to (Bayesian) quadrature and am trying to understand if or how we can use additional information to approximate our definite integral.

Specifically, I am interested in the expected value. This in itself reduces to an integral for continues values

$$ Z = \int f(x)p(x) dx$$

In my problem setting I have access to a dataset $\mathcal{D} = \{x_i,y_i\}_{I=0}^N$ where $y_i = f(x_i) +\epsilon_i$ are noisy evaluations of some function $f$. But in addition I  also have access to the graphical model with which we can factorise the density $p(x)$.

#### Example

Example from page 52 of 'Probabilistic graphical models'.

[image]

This Bayesian network factorises as so $P (I,D,G,L,S) = P(I)P(D)P(G \mid I,D) P(L \mid G) P(S \mid I)$. Now suppose I have access to $\mathcal{D}$ and the above graph and I am interested in the expected grade $\mathbb{E}[G]$ - how can I use the latter information, if at all? We would then be approximating:

$$\mathbb{E}[G] = \int_a^b G \cdot P(G)dG$$
or, exploiting the conditional independences in the graph;
$$\mathbb{E}[G] = \int_a^b G \cdot P(G \mid I,D) P(D) P(I) dG$$

But obviously BQ does not know about this factorisation. And in its vanilla setup it cannot get access to it either. Hence I am wondering if methods exist in which it can be built in? Or perhaps this is a moot point and I have missed something in how BQ works.

The question arises since usually with BQ we do not know how $p(x)$ factorises.

Comment: This is an interesting and probably nontrivial question (from an implementation perspective). Are you already working with BQ in a software environment of some kind?

Comment: Hi there, yeah I am, well the usual suspects: emukit and probnum -the only ones which have decent implementations available (that I could find).

Comment: I was hoping to find some time to look into this but haven't managed to scrounge it up, so I'll just give some high level advice: the factorization is likely to significantly improve the sample-efficiency of the quadrature. But, it's not obvious to me how to implement this using off-the-shelf software. I say this without having done a lit review to confirm the novelty, but it seems to me like coding this up should be considered a research project in its own right.

Comment: Well that's good to know :) this is for a research project. I have done some literature review but I couldn't find much hence why I reached out to SE to see if someone more knowledgeable may know more.

My intuition tells me that this ought to reduce the curse of dimensionality, hence my interest.

Comment: I've sent you an email.